# bitcoin-etl: problems with installing

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, python, mac

I am trying to install bitcoin-etl: https://github.com/blockchain-etl/bitcoin-etl to analyze bitcoin blockchain.

I have Mac OS and python3, I run this in terminal:

`pip install bitcoin-etl`

Also tried this:

`python3 -m pip install bitcoin-etl`

The output is:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bitcoin-etl`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for bitcoin-etl`

---

I have python3 and pip installed:
`python3 -m pip --version`
`pip 21.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Any suggestions?
Thanks!!!

P.S. BTW, if you know any other ways to analyze bitcoin blockchain (I need csv for block counts vs time) your advice would also be very appreciable!

Comment: I can reproduce on macOS again, open an issue here https://github.com/blockchain-etl/bitcoin-etl/issues

Comment: Done! https://github.com/blockchain-etl/bitcoin-etl/issues/48. Thanks!